# Bluetooth Keyboard on Mac Mini

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse and keyboard on my Mac Mini runing 10.13.6 OS.
I am getting a popup whenever the keyboard connects/disconnects, this is very anoying. The popup only occurs for the keyboard not the mouse.  I have disabled notifications but this does not work.  I do a lot of screen captures of video and this keyboard popup is anoying, also I get connect and disconnect at random (bluetooth is NOT a reliable interface) it is subject to many external conditions that play havoc with it.

So in a nutshell is there a way to disable all bluetooth notifications.

Thank you

Comment: What does the pop-up say?

Comment: The pop-up shows a pic of a keyboard with "Connected" or "Lost Connection", it is only for the keyboard not the mouse, both are bluetooth

Comment: Issue is fixed.  I was using a non Apple keyboard, it was turning off to conserve battery life.  I bought an Apple keyboard yesterday and all is ok now.  Apple got another $140 CDN from me.

Comment: I was going to ask if it was an Apple-branded, or Apple-compatible device. I've had clients who have had problems with devices which don't meet specs. I've got a Matias bluetooth keyboard which has been going strong for almost 2 years with nary a glitch.